# search a specific word in BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I am trying to make a python script that reads crunchyroll's page and gives me the ssid of the subtitle.

For example :- http://www.crunchyroll.com/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-1-wriggling-memories-678035

Go to the source code and look for `ssid`,I want to extract the numbers after ssid of this element

```
 <a href="/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-1-wriggling-memories-678035?ssid=154757" title="English (US)">English (US)</a>
```

I want to extract "154757", but I can't seem to get my script working

This is my current script:

```
import feedparser
import re
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.crunchyroll.com/rss/anime')
url1 = feed['entries'][0]['link']
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url1), 'html.parser')
```

How can I modify my code to search and extract that particular number?

Comment: You've asked multiple questions on here and haven't accept any answers. Other users will be more inclined to help if you accept answers to your previous questions first.

Comment: @serk .. done...I couldn't find how to accept them... Instead I was upvoting them :|

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I recommend you take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started with being able to extract the `ssid` for each entry. Note that some of those link don't have any `ssid` so you'll have to account for that with some error catching. No need for `re` or the `urllib2` modules here.

```
import feedparser
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


d = feedparser.parse('http://www.crunchyroll.com/rss/anime')
for url in d.entries:
    #print url.link
    r = requests.get(url.link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    #print soup
    subtitles = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'showmedia-subtitle-text'})
    for ssid in subtitles:
        x = ssid.findAll('a')
        for a in x:
            print a['href']
```

**Output:**

```
--snip--
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=166035
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=165817
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=165819
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=166783
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=165839
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=165989
/i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=166051
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=166011
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=165995
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=165997
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=166033
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=165825
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=166013
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=166009
/urawa-no-usagi-chan/episode-11-if-i-retort-i-lose-678873?ssid=166003
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=166007
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=165969
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=166489
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=166023
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=166015
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=166049
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=165993
/etotama/episode-11-catrat-shuffle-678659?ssid=165981
--snip--
```

There are more but I left them out for brevity. From these results you should be able to easily parse out the `ssid` with some slicing since it looks like the ssid are all 6 digits long. Doing something like:

```
print a['href'][-6:]
```

would do the trick and get you **just** the `ssid`.

Comment: getting :- NameError: name 'requests' is not defined                                                   the line r = requests.get(url.link) is the source of this error....

Comment: you've got to install the `requests` module.

Comment: okay.. so, it started giving me the titles from the rss feed... just need to figure out about ssids.. thank you to get me started... will try and reply in a few hours..

Comment: The `ssid`'s are there in the results (ex: /i-cant-understand-what-my-husband-is-saying/episode-12-baby-skip-beat-678057?ssid=166035) . You'll have to parse them out which shouldn't be too difficult. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @user2408212 Check out the updates I made to the answer to reflect how you can grab **just** the `ssid` from the results.

Comment: yes I just saw.. but,. there's one thing... this is my output http://i.imgur.com/KkknUQL.png    the thing is that.. it's reading from the RSS FEED LINK ... but, I want it to read from feed['entries'][0]['link']   .. look this is my code right now... with yours mixed http://pastebin.com/qwyeS0KE  ...

Comment: I want the ssid to be read from the output this thing generates... http://pastebin.com/DK3pLqw3

Comment: give me a better idea of what you want your output to look like. i'm confused by the code example you posted to pastebin b/c you still have the RSS feed link and `url1` which by using the RSS feed link will give you the same data as `url1`, along with all the other URLs available.

Comment: no no.. my bad... actually your code worked exactly how I wanted... it's just that..to watch the latest episodes in crunchyroll needs you to be logged in.... So, now I have to work on a script that logs me in and keeps the cookies and shows me the ssid of the latest episode... thank you serk for your help... :) ^_^